# Only show taxonomies that belong to the selected store model Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

When a store is selected I would only like to see the taxonomies that belong to the selected store. Does anyone have any idea how I might do this? Either with Ruby or Javascript

```
<h3>Stores Offered In</h3>
  <ul class="multi-column-checkbox">
    <% for store in Store.all %>
        <li><%= check_box_tag "idea[store_ids][]", store.id, 
@idea.stores.include?(store) %> <%= store.name %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <br />

  <h3>Taxonomies Offered In</h3>
  <% for store in Store.all %>
     <% if store.has_taxonomies? %>
          <ul class="multi-column-checkbox">
            <h4><%= store.name %></h4>
            <% for taxonomy in store.taxonomies %>
                <li><%= check_box_tag "idea[taxonomy_ids][]", 
taxonomy.id, @idea.taxonomies.include?(taxonomy) %> <%= taxonomy.name %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
     <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: You have a list of stores with checkboxes (and as I remember from yesterday you're hiding any store that isn't "checked").  Do you want to list only the taxonomies for the stores that are checked in the loop above?

Comment: yes Exactly! I want to list only the taxonomies for the stores that are checked in the loop

Comment: however, I am not hiding any stores anymore. if that changes anything

Comment: so are you letting the users add checks to the stores, and after they do that you want the taxonomies from those stores to display?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want to do!

Comment: You are the first and only person to finally really understand my question. Are you able to help me find a solution?

Comment: I think there might be a more "rails" way to go about this.  Just to verify that you want what I think you want, is this the kind of look you're going for?  http://jsfiddle.net/TdsaL/

Comment: Yes exactly what I am looking for

Comment: but if I deselect the store one check box I would like the taxonomies that are available in store one to disappear

Comment: please delete your duplicate question

Answer (score 0):

Ok -- lots going on here.  First of all, I'm making the assumption that you're using rails 3 or rails 4

Also it looks like this is nested into the ideas model, which not taken into account here, you'll have to modify the code for that.

**Firstly - Try not to make calls directly to a model in a view unless you absolutely have to, that should be done in your controller.  Also, in your view make sure you have a binding element for taxonomies for the jquery call you'll make later.**

`your_main_view_referenced_in_your_question.html.erb`

```
<h3>Stores Offered In</h3>
<ul class="multi-column-checkbox">
  <%- @stores.each do |store| %>
    <li>
    <%= check_box_tag "store[ids]", store.id, false, :data => {:remote => true, :url => url_for( :action => 'get_taxonomies', :id => store.id ), :method => :put}, :class => 'input-large' %>
    <%= store.name %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<br/>
<div id="taxonomies">
</div>
```

**Next you need to create a controller action to respond to your ajax call.**

`stores_controller.rb`

```
### Add an action to let you do an ajax call
def get_taxonomies
  @store = Store.find params[:id]
end
```

**Now you need to create a ujs file that is rendered from your controller action**  In my example I named the controller action get_taxonomies so by default the view rendered will be get_taxonimies.js.erb

`get_taxonomies.js.erb`

```
if ($(".store_" + <%= params[:id] %>).length) {
  $(".store_" + <%= params[:id ] %>).remove();
} else {
  $('#taxonomies').append("<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: '/stores/taxonomy', locals: {stores: @stores } )) %>");
}

if ($("[class^=store_]").length > 0) {
  if ( $('#taxonomies').find('h3').length ) { 
    // do nothing - leave the h3 where it is
  } else {
    $('#taxonomies').prepend("<h3>Store Taxonomies</h3>");
  }
} else {
    $('#taxonomies').find("h3").remove();
}
```

**Now while you could write all your html inline in the js file, it's kind of ugly and easier to edit it later if you put it in a partial - since the js.erb file is calling taxonomy, you'll need a partial with the same name**

`_taxonomy.html.erb`

```
<div class="store_<%=@store.id%>">
  <h4><%= @store.name %></h4>
  <ul class="multi-column-checkbox">
    <%- @store.taxonomies.each do |taxonomy| %>
      <li>
      <%= check_box_tag "[taxonomy_ids][]", taxonomy.id, false %>
      <%= taxonomy.name %>
    <% end %>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: ok I got down everything but the last part. I am a bit confused. I create a new file called _taxonmy.html.erb? where does that file go?

Comment: in the same directory your other view is in

Comment: couldn't I put this last bit of code in the "your_main_view_referenced_in_your_question.html.erb" file

Comment: ujs doesn't work that way -- you can force it to with some if statements but it's not clean

Comment: what happens to the <h3>Taxonomies Offered In</h3>
  <% for store in Store.all %>
     <% if store.has_taxonomies? %>
          <ul class="multi-column-checkbox">?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: refer back to the code in my original question. There is a div for the store and there is a div for the taxonomies.

Comment: when I do everything as you say. I get a "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: There are 2 lines using an each.  so you might need to change the name of the instance variable for the object.  I'm using `@stores` in my example and `@store.taxonomies`, that might need to be something like `@idea.stores` or `@idea.store.taxonomies`